# How do I count files in a folder based on their sizes using visual basic .net (vb.net)?

Tags: vb.net

I want to count files in a folder based on their sizes. For example, how many files that are less than 512KB and how many files that are more than 512KB. Please help me.

Comment: Which part of the problem are you having trouble with?  Getting the list of files?  Getting the size of each file?  Grouping them by size?  Counting the files in each group?  Displaying the results?  Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: Counting the files that have sizes less than 512KB and counting the files that have sizes more than 512KB.

Comment: So presumably you already have a list of the files with their sizes.  What is the type of the objects in that list?  Again, if you could show the code that you have so far, that would help us to help you more effectively.

Comment: Your edit made the situation worse by making the question even more broad.  You need to break it down into smaller logical chunks and tackle each one separately.  Try to do it yourself, and when you can't figure it out, come back here and ask a question about that one specific problem, showing the code you have so far.  If you do that, you'll, not only learn how to program better, but you'll get a much better response from people here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below sub-routine will help you to get the count

```
Sub GetFileDetails(ByVal sFolderPath As String, ByRef Filelessthan512KB As Integer, ByRef FileMorethan512KB As Integer)
        Dim sFiles() As String = Directory.GetFiles(sFolderPath)
        For Each file As String In sFiles
            Dim oFileDetails As New FileInfo(file)

            If (oFileDetails.Length / 1024) < 512 Then
                Filelessthan512KB = Filelessthan512KB + 1
            Else
                FileMorethan512KB = FileMorethan512KB + 1
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, no offence, but this is not a code writing service from what I'm led to believe. Answering the OP question so quickly without any attempt from the OP to show any code is just making questions like this more of a common occurrence....

Comment: @video.baba I wouldn't go so far as to say that it's wrong to answer a broad question like this.  I've certainly been helped by finding similar answers when searching for questions of my own, sometimes.  It's more that it's just not as helpful to the OP and, on even broader questions, it's usually too time consuming for most people to bother to answer.  But I wouldn't say answers to such questions are actively discouraged.

Comment: OK, I understand. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @video.baba No problem.  It's admittedly a gray area that has been debated on meta.  I was a bit unsettled by it too :)

Comment: It worked. Thank you Venkatesh R for understanding me from the beginning and helping me.